# Tensor gradient order of terms

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, vectors, vector-fields, navier-stokes

I am working on some algebraic manipulation with the compressible Navier-Stokes equations, specifically this form, screenshotted from Wikipedia:

[image: Compressible Navier-Stokes Equation]

I'm confused by the gradient operator being applied to the tensor enclosed within the curly braces, which I will denote as tau below. This is a symmetric tensor for my case, which eliminates some potential confusions, but leaves me with one final confusion. What is the correct result of the following operation?

[image: Tensor gradient]

Note that I also am not sure whether the nabla is better represented as a column or row vector, so there is some abuse of notation there as well.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \bullet \tau &=& \left(\hat{\bf e}_i \partial_i\right) \bullet \left(\tau_{jk} \hat{\bf e}_j \hat{\bf e}_k\right) \\ &=& \partial_i \tau_{jk} \left(\hat{\bf e}_i \bullet \hat{\bf e}_j \right)\hat{\bf e}_k \\ &=& \partial_i \tau_{jk} \delta_{ij} \hat{\bf e}_k \\ &=& \partial_i \tau_{ik} \hat{\bf e}_k
\end{eqnarray}
$$

which in two dimensions $\left(x_1 = x, x_2 = y\right)$ is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \bullet \tau = \partial_i \tau_{ik} \hat{\bf e}_k &=& \partial_i \tau_{i1} \hat{\bf e}_1 + \partial_i \tau_{i2} \hat{\bf e}_2 \\ &=& \left(\partial_1 \tau_{11} + \partial_2 \tau_{21}\right) \hat{\bf e}_1 + \left(\partial_1 \tau_{12} + \partial_2 \tau_{22}\right) \hat{\bf e}_2 \\
&=& \left(\frac{\partial\tau_{xx}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\tau_{yx}}{\partial y}\right) \hat{\bf x} + \left(\frac{\partial \tau_{xy}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \tau_{yy}}{\partial y}\right) \hat{\bf y}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Appalling notation, but understandable from the physics:

The body force per unit volume arising from a stress tensor $\sigma_{ij}$ is
$$
F_j= \partial_i \sigma_{ij},
$$
and for a viscous incompressible fluid
$$
\sigma_{ij}=\mu (\partial_i v_j+ \partial_j v_i),
$$
so they must
mean
$$
[\nabla\cdot(\nabla{\bf v}+ (\nabla{\bf v})^T]_j = \partial_i (\partial_i v_j+ \partial_j v_i).
$$

Here $[\ldots]_j$ means the $j$'s component of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eric but it seems to me he only considered the cartesian coordinate system. Note that in many problems you will prefer to work in a cylindrical or spherical system, which means you'll have to distribute the partial derivative over the unit vectors of your coordinate system. That'll lead to some extra terms you will have to bring into your equation:

$$(\sum_{k} \hat{e}_k \nabla_k) \cdot (\sum_{i} \sum_{j} \tau_{ij}\hat{e}_i\hat{e}_j) = \sum_{i} \sum_{j} (\nabla_i\tau_{ij})\hat{e}_j +  \sum_{k} \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \tau_{ij}(\hat{e}_k \cdot \nabla_k\hat{e}_i)\hat{e}_j + \sum_i \sum_j \tau_{ij}\nabla_i \hat{e}_j$$

You can work this out for each coordinate system (your textbook probably provides the answers if you want to check) and in the special case of a cartesian coordinate system you will find the same formula provided earlier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).